# Retrieve the data from sql database and don`t encounter timeout exception

Tags: c#, sql, timeout

I run the below code to extract the data from sql, `q` is a query I use.
The set of data is huge and it takes > 2 min to bring it 
Unfortunately I get an exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout
>   expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
>        completion of the operation or the server is not responding.  This failure occurred while attempting to conne
>       ct to the routing destination. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wr
>       apCloseInAction)
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHa
>       sConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

How can it be resolved and despite the ling time I will be able to retrieve all the data I need.

```
   List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
   {
         connection.Open();
         using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(q, connection))
         {
               using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
               {
                      if (reader.HasRows)
                      {
                           while (reader.Read())
                           {
                               dataList .Add(reader.GetString(0));
                           }
                      }
               }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Set a TimeOut value for your SQL Command.

Comment: As @Rohit suggested set the Time out for the SQL Command. Setting `command.CommandTimeout = 0;` would enable your program/ function to wait for data from SQL.

Comment: @fujiFX - I Would not suggest using `Timeout=0`, it should be set to a reasonable number to fetch data and should not cause deadlocks or infinite waiting.

Comment: @Rohit - Yeah, you correct. Even I would not set it 0 and suggested to set it to 0 since Yakov mentioned that it is huge data table. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the Timeout property of your SQL Command, so that query would throw the Timeout Exception only after waiting those many seconds.

Timeout is an integer value to specify the number of seconds to wait before Timeout exception will be thrown.

Please check [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

The default value is 30 seconds as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx).

This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7023772/1155650) gives a good advice in using Timeout. (quoted below)

> A 1-minute timeout seems reasonable for most queries. An 8+ hour
>   timeout doesn't seem reasonable.
>
> Do you have queries you're expecting to take longer than a minute? If
>   so, raise it to a value you expect to be higher than anything you'd
>   see if everything is working properly, but not so high as to take
>   forever to alert you to a problem. (For example, you might go from 1
>   minute to 5 minutes.)

*Bonus ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008418/1155650))*:

> Setting the CommandTimeout to zero will remove the time limit when
>   waiting for the query to run.
>
> However, if the database goes offline your program will wait
>   indefinitely for something that will not happen, so you should
>   consider setting a long time instead, so that the command will timeout
>   eventually instead of never.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code as follows should allow for the command to have enough time for the results to be returned :
***NOTE: 3 minutes used***

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(q, connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandTimeout = 180;
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    dataList .Add(reader.GetString(0));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

[More info: SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As per OP's problem, *The set of data is huge and it takes > 2 min to bring it*, you advice to set `Timeout=60`?

Comment: Will 3 minutes suffice then?

Comment: It's your suggestion. Also please make it a practice to add reasons to support your answer instead of just code.